# I'm trying to make 2 headers and 2 columns in 1 row

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML Table code
The current problem is at the Date of Birth

```css
.membershipapp-sec-cont th{
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    
    border-width: 0.5px 0.5px 0px 0.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  
    /* Responsive Edit */
    width: 15vw;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    padding-top: 0.7vw;
    padding-bottom: 0.7vw;
    padding-left: 0.7vw;
}

.membershipapp-sec-cont td {
    width: 900px;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    background: #FFFFFF;    
    border-width: 0.5px 0.5px 0px 0.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    /* Responsive Edit */
    width: 45vw;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    height: 3.1vw;

}

.membershipapp-sec-cont input, .membershipapp-sec-cont select {
    width: 862px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;

    /* Responsive Edit */
    width: 44.9vw;
    height: 3vw;
    font-size: 1.1vw;

}

.membershipapp-sec-cont input#DoubleColumn {
    width: 300px;

    /* Responsive Edit */
    width: 15vw;
}

.membershipapp-sec-cont td#DoubleColumn {
    width: 300px;
    
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="title">Title :</label> </th>
        <td> <select name="title" required>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="FirstName">First Name :</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="FirstName" required/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="LastName">Last Name :</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="LastName" required/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="CompanyName">Company Name :</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="CompanyName" required/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="Occupation">Occupation</label> </th>
        <td> <input type="text" name="Occupation" required/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <label for="DoB">Date of Birth :</label> </th>
        <td> <input id="DoubleColumn" type="date" name="DoB" required/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I wanted to do

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGj2G.png)

And this is what happened

[Disaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkm73.png)

This is the style

I tried using an id on that specific row to make it's width smaller, but it is not working.
I had the table originally "Width 100%" but I changed that so the table th and td make up for 1200 pixels, because the page's width is 60vw

Whenever I try to add another th and td in the row, it'll go to the outside of the table to the right, expanding and causing another table to form. I cannot make the td smaller then the rest.

Comment: Study this link for getting what you expect


https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Despite not using bootstrap, I could learn from this. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear that I could be of some help. Take care

Comment: @Raky I don't think sharing links passes the standard on this site for being helpful. This is one step short of "google it" as a response.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do but I think you want to look at "colspan" and "rowspan". Btw. it's better not to use tables if you don't need to. They are not much mobile friendly.

Comment: @Ortund, Adam E found the link helpful to learn. I didn't want supply readymade code because it would kill the learning spirit. Since it was basic concept, i just pointed the direction to takeoff. Kindly reconsider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adam E, Looking at comments from @Ortund
Here's the code. Hope you like it and it works for you

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input, select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1vw;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

tr {
    height: 1vw;
}
```

```html
    <table >
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="title">Title :</label> </th>
            <td id="ExtendedCell" colspan="4"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <select name="title" required="">
                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                    <option value="Mdm">Mdm</option>
                    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="FirstName">First Name :</label> </th>
            <td id="ExtendedCell" colspan="4"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="FirstName" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="LastName">Last Name :</label> </th>
            <td id="ExtendedCell" colspan="4"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="LastName" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="CompanyName">Company Name :</label> </th>
            <td id="ExtendedCell" colspan="4"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="CompanyName" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="Occupation">Occupation</label> </th>
            <td id="ExtendedCell" colspan="4"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="text" name="Occupation" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <label for="DoB">Date of Birth :</label> </th>
            <td id="DoubleColumn" colspan="2"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="date" name="DoB" required="">
            </td>
            <th> <label for="DoB">Nationality :</label> </th>
            <td id="Nationality" colspan="2"> <!-- Extend the span -->
                <input type="text" name="nationality" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```